# How to attach image in csv file using yii ECSVExport extensions

Tags: php, yii, yii-extensions

```
Yii::import('application.extensions..ECSVExport');

$filename = 'filename.csv';
$csv = new ECSVExport($sheet_generation);

$csv->setOutputFile($outputFile);

$content = $csv->toCSV();   

Yii::app()->getRequest()->sendFile($filename, $content, "text/csv", false);
```

Comment: Its possible, but do you know what CSV actually means ?

Comment: CSV means -Character Separated File

Comment: Its Comma Seperated values. And see here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333522/how-can-i-include-image-into-csv

Comment: i want to display the logo of the company only in csv file