# Export Image to CSV

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, export-to-csv

Hi i am Trying to Export .csv file with QR Code Generation.

I Have Done QR Code Generation and CSV Export but i want to Generated QR Code image Bind to my .csv File.

Here is What i am done..

```
 protected void lnkbtnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int NoOfCode = int.Parse(txtNoOfCode.Text);
            DateTime ExpiryDate = DateTime.Parse(txtExpiryDate.Text.ToString());
            string csv = string.Empty;

            //Add the Header row for CSV file.
            csv += "Code" + ',' + "Expiry On" + ',' + "QR Code" + ',';
            csv += "\r\n";

            for (int i = 0; i < NoOfCode; i++)
            {
                string GeneratedCode = GenerateString(8);
                Tuple<int, string, int> tuple = Code.AddData(GeneratedCode, ExpiryDate);

                QRCodeGenerator qrGenerator = new QRCodeGenerator();
                QRCodeGenerator.QRCode qrCode = qrGenerator.CreateQrCode(GeneratedCode, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
                System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image imgBarCode = new System.Web.UI.WebControls.Image();
                imgBarCode.Height = 150;
                imgBarCode.Width = 150;
                byte[] byteImage;
                using (Bitmap bitMap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20))
                {
                    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        bitMap.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
                        byteImage = ms.ToArray();
                        imgBarCode.ImageUrl = "data:image/png;base64," + Convert.ToBase64String(byteImage);
                    }
                    plBarCode.Controls.Add(imgBarCode);

                    csv += "\r\n";

                    **csv += GeneratedCode.ToString() + ',' + ExpiryDate.ToString() + ',' + bitMap + ',';**
                }
            }

            Response.Clear();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=SqlExport.csv");
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.ContentType = "application/text";
            Response.Output.Write(csv);
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

        }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: CSV is a text file... Why would you want to store a picture in a text file??? See a similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333522/how-can-i-include-image-into-csv

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, you can't save image within csv file. You need to change the file extension to do this [e.g .xls or .xlsx].

Comment: i am trying the same but when i append the bitmap image in the excel file it is being saved as string `System.Drawing.Bitmap` not as image... did you solve it?

Comment: You can't Base64 encode the bytes and store text that in a text file?

Comment: @User7291 you need to save the Bitmap in the file system first. Then insert it in the excel file.

Comment: @SeanAnderson you can save Base64 text in text file, but that's not the purpose here I guess.