# Upload image from my computer to remote

Tags: php, html, angularjs

I have an image in this location `E:/image/flower.jpg`

I need to upload it to a remote server. My idea is just `base64encode` the image and get the content like this.

```
 $imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents('E:/image/flower.jpg'));
```

It is working if am working on my localhost, but on my webserver, it is not reading my image. Plz help me.

Comment: We really need to know more about your web server and your local machine to debug this.  Have you made sure that the web server process on the server has read permissions to the file?

Comment: You probably will have no access to system if you are using a shared hosting, also depending of web-user permissions.

Comment: Yah. Because our project idea is getting details of users. the user will upload a csv file with some data to our server. From there we will get the image location in their computer. We need to read that image base64encode data and save in our db. It is reading the csv file. Bt image content is not.we dont need the image to get uploaded, bt we need the content of image

Answer (score 0):

Try to get access to the image from relative URL instead of absolute file path.

So:

```
$imgData = base64_encode(file_get_contents('./image/flower.jpg'));
```

Comment: Your code will work only if the image resides in the server.. Bt it is like uploading a new image to server

Comment: @athi The only way I think you'll be able to achieve that is uploading the image to your server (storing the images as .png /.gif ..) and adding the image link into the proper csv field. Take a look to this issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333522/how-can-i-include-image-into-csv)

Comment: Let me know if you get it works in your main idea way, please @athi